# Moving the google map according to the marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I want to move the google map according to the marker. I set the defaultCenter but when i got my current position with lat and lng marker is move correctly but google map is not moving according to the marker.

Here is the code

```
import { GoogleMap, withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Map(props) {
    const { latitude, longitude } = useSelector(state => state.location);
    const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState({ lat: 42.360081, lng: 7.665440 });


    return (
        <GoogleMap defaultZoom={4}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: (latitude ? latitude : current.lat), lng: (longitude ? longitude : current.lng) }}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: (latitude ? latitude : current.lat), lng: (longitude ? longitude : current.lng) }} />}
        </GoogleMap>
    )
}


const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

const App = () => {
    return (
        <WrappedMap
            isMarkerShown={true}
            googleMapURL={`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]-e2c2H2jAcFw`}
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: `75vh` }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-frog-1f8u2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: In this i am using react-google-map. By default lat and lng has value. When i got the current position marker and circle move rapidly without animation. 
And also i want to load geoJson but i don't know how to do this in react-google-map.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately your codesandbox is not working; some dependencies are missing. Please fix it so that the sandbox can be run properly and your map is displayed.

Comment: [GoogleMap link](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-frog-1f8u2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: In this component marker is also not showing please help me

Comment: Try using a variable for your map and then passing it into your marker function. Check out the answer I'll post in a minute and let me know if this helps and fixes the issue. If not, let me know and I'll help you further and modify my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning `new window.google.maps.Map` to a variable `map` and then add `setMarker(createMarker(map))` in your `createGoogleMap` function.

Now the marker is placed on the map, and the map is centered on its position because you added the same coordinates.

See the code below:

```
googleMapScript.addEventListener("load", () => {
    setGoogleMap(createGoogleMap());
});

...

let createGoogleMap = () => {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(googleMapRef.current, {
        zoom: 16,
        center: {
            lat: 43.642567,
            lng: -79.387054,
        },
        // disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

    setMarker(createMarker(map));
}


let createMarker = (map) => {
    const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: 43.642567, lng: -79.387054 },
        map: map,
    })
    return marker
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You so much Buddy, u are awesome, can you tell me what was the problem  in this??

Comment: Sure! Happy to help :) The problem was scope-related, you were initializing the marker to a null variable because you were not passing into it the reference to your created map. Notice how you don't return anything or assign any variable to `window.google.maps.Map`. With a map variable containing the map reference as a parameter, the marker can now be placed on the map without issues.

Comment: Thanks You so much buddy.